# Error in Sitecore on SavedItemRemoteEvent anyone else?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I get this error in the Sitecore logs and I cannot figure it out.

**Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 140228)
February 28, 2014
.NET Framework 4.0.30319.34209**

```
Heartbeat 10:35:32 ERROR Exception while handling event Sitecore.Data.Eventing.Remote.SavedItemRemoteEvent 
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException 
Message: Invalid event arg type: Sitecore.Data.Events.ItemSavedRemoteEventArgs. Expected: SitecoreEventArgs 
Source: Sitecore.Kernel 
at Sitecore.Events.Event.ExtractParameters(EventArgs args) 
at Sitecore.Events.Event.ExtractParameter(EventArgs args, Int32 index) 
at Sitecore.Events.Event.ExtractParameter[T](EventArgs args, Int32 index) 
at Sitecore.Buckets.Caching.DisplayedInSearchResultsCache.StartProcess(EventArgs e) 
at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) 
at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) 
at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSavedRemote(Object sender, ItemSavedRemoteEventArgs args) 
at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) 
at Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider.RaiseEvent(Object event, Type eventType, EventContext context)
```

Please help.

Comment: Is there somethings special in your <event name="item:saved:remote">

Comment: What servers you have? and one which one is the error?. the scaling guide tells more over the configuration. Is there somethings strange inside the database table EventQueue on Core

Comment: <handler type="Sitecore.Globalization.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemSavedRemote" />
        <handler type="Sitecore.Rules.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemSavedRemote" /> This is what I have in the <event name="item:saved:remote">. It looks pretty standard. The error occurs on the cms server.

Comment: I am currently investigating EventQueue to see something different.

Comment: Any updates? I'm having this same error on the same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Sitecore CMS and DMS 7.2 rev. 140526 (7.2 Update-2). Click [here](https://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog/Release%20History%20SC72.aspx) for release notes. Check 404817.

Replied on Sitecore Community Forum.

https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/p/1423/4077#4077